# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to map object properties from initial state object. I can get all properties except the nested `milesotnes`.

The initial state is defined in components class constructor like so:

```js
class GoalView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataGoal: {},
      uid: firebaseAuth().currentUser.uid,
      currentGoalId: this.props.match.params.goalId,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+this.state.currentGoalId);
    dataGoalRef.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({
          dataGoal: snap.val(),
          currentGoalId: this.props.match.params.goalId,
        });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.state = {
      currentGoalId: null,
    };
  }
  
  ...
  
}
```

I am getting the `currentGoalId` from a React Router V4 Link:

```
<Link title="Open goal" to={"/app/goal/id"+key}>Open goal</Link>
```

which is in a higher order component. The render method of the current GoalView component looks like so:

```js
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <main className="content">
          <p>{this.state.dataGoal.description}</p><br /><br />

            {Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal.milestones).map( (milestoneKey) => {
              const milestonesData = this.state.dataGoal.milestones[milestoneKey];

              return <div className="milestone-wrap" key={milestoneKey}>
                       <label className="milestone-label truncate">{milestonesData.name}</label>

                     </div>
            })}

        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the state:

[image]

> I am getting `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` from this
>   row `{Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal.milestones).map( (milestoneKey)
>   => {...}`

but the `description` in render method right above that row is rendering just fine. Anyone has some ideas, please?

Thank you,
Jakub

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before using `Object.keys()` put the check on `dataGoal`, like this:

`this.state.dataGoal.milestones && Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal.milestones)`

**Reason:** You are fetching the data from server it will take time, until that `this.state.dataGoal.milestones` will be `undefined`.

Or you can hold the rendering until you didn't get the data by using a `bool` in state variable.

Check this, it will produce the same error:

```js
let a = {};

Object.keys(a.a).map(el => console.log(el));
```

**Suggestion:** Binding of `lifecycle methods` are not required, use them directly, so remove the `arrow function` with `lifecycle methods`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mayank for all your suggestions. I thought it has to do something with that I just couldn't make it work. Any other suggestions about the code above? I am new to React so any help is appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: rest everything is proper, one more thing that i want to suggest you ( i used to follow), try to make render method as small as possible means if you want to run some loop to create ui or other js conditions, put that in a function and call that function inside render, it will help you to manage the code and others to understand what you are doing :)

Comment: Thank you for your revision and recommendations. :)